# oracle filter on explain plan partitions

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm making a proof of concept and I'm experimenting a strange behaviour.
I have a table partitioned by range by a date field and the cost of a query changes a lot if I set a fixed date or one created by SYSDATE.

These are the explain plans:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM TP_TEST_ELEMENTO_TRAZABLE ET
  3   WHERE ET.FEC_RECEPCION
  4  BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
  5  ;

5109 filas seleccionadas.


Plan de Ejecuci¾n
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1151442660

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                            |  5008 | 85136 |  4504   (8)| 00:00:55 |       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                   |                            |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                            |  5008 | 85136 |  4504   (8)| 00:00:55 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TP_TEST_ELEMENTO_TRAZABLE  |  5008 | 85136 |  4504   (8)| 00:00:55 |   KEY |   KEY |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-2)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-1))
   3 - filter("ET"."FEC_RECEPCION">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-2) AND "ET"."FEC_RECEPCION"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-1))


EstadÝsticas
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
        376  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
     137221  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       4104  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        342  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       5109  rows processed
```

Using fixed dates:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM TP_TEST_ELEMENTO_TRAZABLE ET
  3   WHERE ET.FEC_RECEPCION
  4  BETWEEN  TO_DATE('26/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND  TO_DATE('27/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  5  ;

5109 filas seleccionadas.


Plan de Ejecuci¾n
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3903280660

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                            |  5008 | 85136 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                            |  5008 | 85136 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |   607 |   608 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TP_TEST_ELEMENTO_TRAZABLE  |  5008 | 85136 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |   607 |   608 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("ET"."FEC_RECEPCION"<=TO_DATE(' 2017-02-27 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))


EstadÝsticas
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
        376  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
     137221  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       4104  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        342  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       5109  rows processed
```

What's the difference that produces a cost of 4504 and a cost of 11?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The short answer is: "cost" is not meant to compare two different queries (even if they seem very similar); they are **only** meant to compare different plans for one query at a time. When comparing different queries, you are better off comparing cardinality estimates.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628

Comment: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/cost-is-time-again/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is because when you use SYSDATE, it has the potential to need any partition. For example, if you are daily partitioned, then the partition you need to access will be different between today and tomorrow. As such, the plan is KEY:KEY, meaning that the actual partition is resolved at runtime.

With a fixed date, we know at compile time which partition it resolves to. And since it resolves to a single partition, it's more "accurately" costed.